# 'module' object has no attribute 'Dot'

Tags: python, networkx, pydot

I'm a beginner in python, and i'm trying to draw a graph using:

```
`nx.write_dot(G, "%s.dot"%(image))`
```

in a defined function. When I excute the program, I'm getting this error:

```
File "sim.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()

File "sim.py", line 30, in main
    sol.run() 

File "C:\Python27\My sim\Solution.py", line 221, in run
    self.drawGraph(G, "solution1")

File "C:\Python27\My sim\Solution.py", line 227, in drawGraph
    nx.write_dot(G, "%s.dot"%(image))

File "<decorator-gen-232>", line 2, in write_dot

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py", line 220, in _open_file

result = func(*new_args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pydot.py", line 58, in write_dot

P=to_pydot(G)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pydot.py", line 197, in to_pydot

P = pydot.Dot(graph_type=graph_type,strict=strict,**graph_defaults)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Dot'
```

**It seems it is a Windows os problem (I'm on win7), because my colleague can run the same script on his ubuntu machine without any error.**

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can use dir(P) to see the methods/properties of a variable.

Comment: It seems like the File commands begin with quotes, but don't end in them consistently; is this just a manual typing error?

Comment: @MichelKeijzers: Please tell how how can I do it? (I'm beginning with python)

Comment: @MathBio: It's just a typing error in the forum

Comment: what's 'My sim' folder? and what's in Solution.py?

Comment: @BernardRouhi: 'My sim' folder is containing py files that I'm excuting. The main file is sim.py which is calling Solution.py; the latter contains my graph drawing function that is using nx.write_dot

Comment: add the code  "print dir(P)"

Comment: @MichelKeijzers: it isn't showing anything...

Answer (score 0):

you are doing the tutorial **Drawing graphs** right?

here how it work:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3)])
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

**Edit:** if you didn't install matplotlib, just open command line and type:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

matplotlib is optional, it doesn't come with networkx, you have to install it.

also for saving the **.dot** file just add this line:

```
nx.write_dot(G,'C:/file.dot')
```

**Edit:** without **matplotlib** will be like so:

```
import networkx as nx

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3)])
nx.draw(G)
nx.write_dot(G,'C:/file.dot')
```

I notice in your code `nx.write_dot(G, "%s.dot"%(image))` you didn't define `image` and G, the error should be from one of those.

but if you want to install c++ compiler, i suggest downloading [Visual C++ Compiler](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41151) 33mb or [Microsoft visual studio community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx), they are free.

Comment: I have tried this method, but when I wanted to install matplotlib, it failed because it requires visual c++ if I remember wellans I don't have much space on my machine to install new softwares; so i'm dealing with my_dot problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Betty i see... you can just ignore `plt` on 2nd and 7th line.

Comment: G and image are my function attributes, so when i'm calling this function, there is the error.
I used your last code propostion, but it has an error:  ImportError: Matplotlib required for draw().I think I'll try to free some space and install visual c++.Thanks for your interaction!

Comment: @Betty `draw()` is one of `networkx` functions, it shouldn't show `Matplotlib` error. after importing `networkx`, you can check list of functions with `dir (networkx)`.

Comment: yes, there is `draw()` function, but can't understand why it said it requires `Matplotlib` ?!!

Comment: @Betty: maybe try to edit your question and put your main source code in there or link of it to your github / bitbucket / gitlab or something.

Comment: "but can't understand why it said it requires Matplotlib".  `draw` requires matplotlib because it builds on matplotlib commands to draw the graph.  If you don't have matplotlib, you're not going to be able to draw much of anything with python.

Comment: @bear - if you don't have matplotlib, `draw` won't work.  Here's the [source](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw)

Comment: @Joel: you are right, i just uninstall the **matplotlib** and try the code, it show `ImportError: Matplotlib required for draw()` that's my bad, thanks for pointing it out.